# Javascript React: Button not excuting function when button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, function

I was wondering if anyone can help me. I am putting the letters of the alphabet in an interval with the press of a button. I got the start button to execute the const "startFunction" to work!. The Letter interval is working perfectly. However, the stop button is not working which holds the function to stop the letter interval. So I was wondering if there is anything I am doing wrong. Thank you so much.

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Chalkboard from './chalkboard/chalkboard';
import LevelBoxes from './levelBoxes/levelBoxes';
import StartStop from './startStopButtons/startStopButtons';

function App() {
var _timer;

// Function that starts the letter interval
  const startFunction = () => {
    var allLetters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
    var y = 0;
    let start = 0;
        for (y = 0; y < allLetters.length; y++) {
           setTimeout(() => getRandom(allLetters), y*1000);
         } 
    }
// Stops startFunction
  const stopButton = () => {
        clearTimeout(_timer);
        clearTimeout(getRandom);
      }

  // letter interval function
  function getRandom (letters) {
    var randomSet = letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
    console.log('set random' , randomSet)
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = randomSet;
    _timer = setTimeout(() => getRandom(letters), 1000);
};

return (
    <div className="App">
     
        <h1>Letter Interval Application</h1>
        <Chalkboard />
        
        <button 
        onClick={startFunction} 
        id="startButton">Start interval</button>

        <button 
        onClick={stopButton} 
        id="stopButton">Stop interval</button>

        <LevelBoxes />
         
    </div>
  ); }

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a loop inside `startFunction`, so you just set many `timeouts`, but you don't clear them in your code.

There is some duplications in your logic. Since `getRandom` is a recursive function, you may only need call it once, and it will call itself after 1 second.

So, I suggest, you refactor your `startFunction` as the following:

```
const startFunction = () => {
    var allLetters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
    getRandom(allLetters);
}
```

`getRandom` will immediately run, and do the job it should do. Because you have already stored the timeoutID to `_timer`. Then when `stopButton` is called, you just need to call `clearTimeout(_timer)`, `getRandom` should stop calling itself.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling **clearTimeout(getRandom)** in your **stopButton** function, but I can't seem to find getRandom anywhere.

Change this line from

```
setTimeout(() => getRandom(allLetters), y*1000);
```

to

```
getRandom = setTimeout(() => getRandom(allLetters), y*1000);
```